# Issues with Apache Kafka Quickstart

Tags: apache-kafka

I am new to Kafka and seem to be having several issues with the 'Quickstart' guide for Apache Kafka found here:
https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart#quickstart_kafkaconnect

Ultimately I am trying to learn how to load a kafka queue with many kafka messages and so the Step 7 part of this Quickstart guide seemed relevant.

I installed the binary download (Scala 2.11  - kafka_2.11-1.1.0.tgz ) found here:
https://kafka.apache.org/downloads

I had initially tried to jump straight to step 7 but realised after finding this question ([Kafka Connect implementation errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35472502/kafka-connect-implementation-errors?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)) I had to do the few steps prior to that

Therefore I followed the first step successfully:

```
tar -xzf kafka_2.11-1.1.0.tgz
cd kafka_2.11-1.1.0
```

Then I followed step 2:

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

But I get the error

```
ERROR Unexpected exception, exiting abnormally (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain)
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:67)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.configure(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:90)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.runFromConfig(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:117)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.initializeAndRun(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:87)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.main(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:53)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:116)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:78)
```

But when I run the next command in that same step:

```
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

The Kafka server seems to run successfully?

So then I tried to continue to step 3 to create a topic:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test
```

But this produces the error:

```
Error while executing topic command : Replication factor: 1 larger than available brokers: 0.
[2018-04-09 14:13:26,908] ERROR org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidReplicationFactorException: Replication factor: 1 larger than available brokers: 0.
 (kafka.admin.TopicCommand$)
```

Then trying step 4:

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test
```

This seems to work and I can write a message but then I get a connection error (which is probably due to the fact previous steps haven't worked successfully)

```
kafka_2.11-1.1.0 user$ bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test
>This is a message
[2018-04-09 14:17:52,631] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2018-04-09 14:17:52,687] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

Does anyone know why these issues are occurring and how I can fix them? I can't find anymore inforomation in that tutorial about these problems

Comment: You would need to start zookeeper first before starting kafka server i guess

Comment: @nitnamby yes I realise that most of the subsequent issues probably relate to the fact that the command `bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties` isn't working correctly

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, you have something running on the default port for ZK. Either close it or change the zookeeper properties file to use another port.

Answer (score 0):

Address `localhost:2181` is already in use. Since Zookeeper cannot start, then Kafka brokers won't start too. `replication-factor` **must** be less or equal to the number of available brokers, and since no broker is available then the following error will be reported (even if you are using `--replication-factor 1`).

```
Error while executing topic command : Replication factor: 1 larger than available brokers: 0.
[2018-04-09 14:13:26,908] ERROR org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidReplicationFactorException: Replication factor: 1 larger than available brokers: 0.
 (kafka.admin.TopicCommand$)
```

You either need stop the process which is running in 2181 or change the ZK default port to a port which is not currently in use.

To see what is running (PID)  in port 2181, run

```
lsof -i -n -P | grep 2181
```

If you want to kill that process, then run

```
kill -9 PID
```

where PID is the process ID which you can get from `lsof` command.

Otherwise, you need to change the port in the `zookeeper.properties` file by modifying the parameter `clientPort=2181`. And finally, you need to change `zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181` parameter in the `server.properties` file accordingly.